# How can I use launchd to auto update brew?

Tags: homebrew, launchd

I followed the instructions on the page [Creating Launch Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001762-104142) and created (as root) my own plist file named `com.personal.brew.plist` and located in `/Library/LaunchDeamons/`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.personal.brew</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>brew</string>
        <string>upgrade</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The issue is that it's not doing anything. What I want to achieve is have brew check for upgrades once every week (ex.: each Sunday), after boot. How can I change the script to do this?

I'm on Mojave 10.14.1.

Comment: You didn’t specify a time or interval when it’s supposed to run

Comment: You do *not* want to do this.  Automatic unattended updates are a bad idea.